# Выпадающий текст HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css

Всем привет, как сделать чтобы при нажатии на текст, выпадался другой текст ниже. Как на скриншоте 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `<details><summary>Меня забанили</summary>Если вы...</details>`

Answer (score 2):

```css
body {
  font-family: roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.info {
  background-color: #f9f9ff;
  padding: 10px 25px;
}

.info__switch {
  display: none;
}

.info__body {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.info__switch:checked~.info__body {
  max-height: 100px;
}

.info__headline::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -18px;
  top: 4px;
  border: 6px solid #39739d;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
}

.info__switch:checked~.info__headline::before {
  transform: rotate(180deg) translateY(6px);
}

.info__headline {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  user-select: none;
  color: #39739d;
  font-weight: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.info__headline:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <input id="info__body_1" class="info__switch" type="checkbox">
  <label for="info__body_1" class="info__headline">Вебинары, которые помогут блеснуть эрудицией!</label>
  <div class="info__body">
    Вебинары образовательного проекта Level One — современный формат интеллектуального досуга, который будет интересен всем, кто хочет узнать что-то новое. Всего за пару часов вы совершите путешествие в увлекательный мир науки и искусства. Талантливые лекторы
    поделятся своими знаниями, доступно расскажут о важных научных открытиях и расширят ваш кругозор.

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Можно и легче...

```
<details>Еще раз нажмешь 2 ПОСТАВЛЮ!<summary>Нажми сюда...</summary></details>
```

Это можно преобразить...
Для этого открываем свой файл CSS.

?

ЧТО БУДЕТ ЕСЛИ

Если вы будете редактировать тег  details, то вы отредактируйте ВСЕ надписи и в теге summary, и в details.

Если вы будете редактировать тег SUMMARY возьму на пример. вы прописали по CSS вот такой код...

```
summary {
         color: white;
        }
```

то у вас получиться summary белым цветом, а details будет базовым цветом - то есть черным.

НЕМНОЖКО ПРО КОНЕКТ CSS

Тут будет 3 примера, как подсоединить CSS.

1. Самый легкий способ. Написать команду и ТАМ УЖЕ внутри написать так:

   у вас получиться текст красного цвета.
2. Средний по сложности способ. вам нужно прописать  и между ними уже редактировать нужные вам программы.
3. Наверно немножко сложный способ. Нужно прописать  между командами НЕ НУЖНО ничего писать.